# Динамический import и export

Tags: async-await, promise

Есть два файла.

module.js

```
export default {
get: async () => { return 'key' }
}
```

Подключаемый модуль который должен выполнить асинхронные действия.

и index.js

```
const xxx = require('./module/index.js')
module['default'].get()
```

синхронный поток чтения. Вызывается асинхронная функция.
возвращается promise

```
Promise {<resolved>: "key"}
__proto__:Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]:"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]:"key"
```

Как соотносятся синхронные части кода с асинхронными ? 
Есть ли возможность остановить чтение (использовать await) в index.js файле.

Comment: Я с динамическим импортом разобраться хотел. 
Нашёл хорошую статью на эту тему. 
Примеры в таком же вопросе посмотрел, разобрался.
Но для понимания процесса мне помогла статья https://medium.com/@WebReflection/javascript-dynamic-import-export-b0e8775a59d4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из асинхронной функции всегда возвращается Promise. Как следствие, вам нужно либо не использовать асинхронную функцию, либо использовать конструкцию `await` для "разворачивания" promise.

Например, вот так:

```
const xxx = require('./module/index.js');
(async () => {
    const val = await xxx.default.get();
    console.log(val); // Выведет "key"
})();
```

Comment: Так ошибку выдаёт.
main.js?1c90:45 Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...) is not a function
    at eval (main.js?1c90:45)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:2486)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
    at fn (app.js:89)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:2381)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:679)
    at app.js:725
    at app.js:728

Comment: Это у вас что-то со сборкой не то. Код-то рабочий...

Answer (score 0):

В таком виде как я его привёл не будет работать.
Невозможно вне асинхронной функции получить данные, так как используется 
однопроцессный Event-Loop с неблокирующим I/O.
Какую бы я переменную не определил она прочитается раньше чем будет получено разрешение promise.
Но это возможно в рамках функции.

[JavaScript dynamic import() & export](https://medium.com/@WebReflection/javascript-dynamic-import-export-b0e8775a59d4)

```
(async () => {
const module = require('./module/index.js')
const val = await module['default'].get()
console.log('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~', val)
})()
```